# custom Loss - Iteration over tf.Tensor works fine on dummy data but not in model.fit_generator

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am implementing a custom loss func:

```
def wmse(y_true, y_pred):

    gt_bin_dict = {"0.0": 4, "0.1": 16, "0.2": 75, "0.3": 62} # and so on till 1.0

    weight_freq = []
    for i in y_true:

        # i in y_true can be a value between 0 - 1 and we get the first 3 
        # elems from the str(i) i.e. if i is 0.15 str(i)[:3] == 0.1 which
        # used as a key (in gt_bin_dict) will return 16.

        weight_freq.append(1./gt_bin_dict[str(i.numpy())[:3]])

    loss = 0
    for i in range(len(y_true)):
        loss += weight_freq[i] * K.square(y_true[i].numpy() - y_pred[i].numpy())

    return loss
```

When i run the above function on my dummy data, it runs without errors and gives me a proper output.

```
a = tf.constant([0.15, 0.2, 0.33])
b = tf.constant([0.43, 0.57, 0.68])

loss = wmse(a, b)
print(loss)

# output:
# tf.Tensor(0.008043971, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

but when I start training my model (using `model.fit_generator()` i get the following error:

```
OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed: AutoGraph did not convert this function. Try decorating it directly with @tf.function.
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Just a heads up, I switched from keras to tf.keras (tf version 2.2.0) and im sure im not mixing keras and tf.keras anymore. (i will keep double checking if that is the issue)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your loss is a weighted MSE... you can also use directly TF functionality to do this

```
model.compile('adam', 'mse')
```

when fitting you can set the sample weight parameter

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train, sample_weight=weight_freq, ...)
```

where `weight_freq` is an array of the same length of your X_train

---

with `gt_bin_dict` as a fixed dict you can simply get the weight for your samples in this way

```
y_true = np.random.uniform(0,1, 1000) # just for example
W_dict = {1:10,2:83,3:23,4:43,5:42,6:24,7:34,8:23,9:12,10:99} # just for example

y_true_bin = np.digitize(a, bins=np.linspace(0,1, 11))
weight_freq = [W_dict[i] for i in y_true_bin]
weight_freq = np.asarray(weight_freq)
```

and then apply the weights during training as introduced above

Comment: Hey thanks for you answer, so heres the thing, the `weighted_freq` var is actually based on the y_trues in that batch. So based on what the batch contains for that epoch the weighted_freq will be different (and will be the same length as batch size). Would this work in that case?

Comment: ok, I understand... do you have a piece of code/logic that computes the weights, so I can adjust your loss

Comment: Hey, i edited the question with how i compute the weights_freq, basically its the inverse of frequency (value) given by the dict with the key being the first 3 items if y_true is read as a str. (this is so i can store the value as 'bins'

Comment: I know... but I don't see any relation with the batch... gt_bin_dict is always fixed?

Comment: sorry didnt get notif, yes gt_bin_dict is always fixed (unless more data). The relation to batch is, we need to apply a weight to the loss based on the frequency of our y_trues in the batch. if in one instance our batch contains (0.1, 0.4) y_trues (batch_size=2) then our weight_freq will only be applied for those y_trues from values obtained from the dict for them.

Comment: So so if our y_true is above and y_pred is (0.2, 0.5) then the formula would be (loss=1/4 * (0.1 - 0.2)^2 + 1/62 * (0.3 - 0.5)^2). is batch_size=2. The 1/4 and 1/62 are inverse from the gt_bin_dict

Comment: ok so no problem... keras deals the batch computation automatically ( github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/10426#issuecomment-397485072 ). if gt_bin_dict is fixed you can manipulate outside one for all... I edited my answer

Comment: Thanks, just for clarification, the second part of the answer, i can add that to my loss function?

Comment: make the weight_freq computation outside... use the mse with sample_weight

Comment: okay so i see the edit made to the answer and passing the weight_freq and sample_weights. Its quite, early int he morning here so Ill play around with this tomorrow and let you know :) thanks

Comment: Sure... no problem! let me know

Comment: Okay so as I am using a generator object to feed data into the model, sample_weight does not work. I had to add the weight_freq as part of the generator. Marking this as correct as it defi helped! :) Maybe you can note the above in the answer or to read the comments. cheers mate

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bug, and it would be worth filing a github issue.

At any rate, you could try to work around it by annotating `wmse` with `@tf.function`. If you do that, note that you will likely need to use a `tf.TensorArray` for `weight_freq` instead of a Python list.

Comment: Not just that but it goes into a rabbit-hole, i would have to change `.numpy()` to `.eval()` which would then force me to declare a tf.Session(), which then says my graphs are from different sessions, and so on. instead the marked solution worked well with a minor change.

Comment: Yes, it's definitely best to use the built-in loss. Note that you wouldn't use `eval()` ot `tf.Session` inside tf.function. In fact you shouldn't have called `numpy()` in the first place. You'd simply return the tensors and the runtime would handle the numpy conversions, if necessary.